# why are all database access methods within the asp.net Identity api marked async

Tags: asp.net, async-await, asp.net-identity

Consider this simple pseudo code

```
User logs in 
 Application access database to try retrieve the login using provided password and username
if record is found then show requested page otherwise display login with error message
```

How does this benefit from being async? Surely the application can't continue  until the database has searched for the record.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is more general question about `async-await`. Methods executed this way are not blocking the executing thread and application is available to do other work, while DB is returning with the result. This means that your application can serve other request (from other user perhaps) while waiting for DB to return the result.

There are a lot have been written about `async-await`. You can start from here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2013/12/18/c-async-and-await-why-do-we-need-them-part-1.aspx

And, FYI, Identity library have non-async methods provided as extension methods. So if your application is non-async, you don'have to use `async` keywords all the way through your app.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct in that a response cannot be returned to the requestor until the database has searched for the record and found a result and the request has finished processing.

By making the data access asynchronous however will allow the request thread to be freed and returned to the thread pool to service other requests and when the data operation later completes, a request thread can be taken from the thread pool and continue with the rest of the request.

In this way, a request thread is not blocked from performing other useful work whilst waiting on the DB operation, as it would be if the method were synchronous.

Comment: For clarity, does it make sense to say then, that in the above, the actual "process" of db lookup and the subsequent display part (in the context of a web/asp.net app) is still "synchronous" (it's own "thread")? I (think) I get it - more so when running something like a console app where "other processes" aren't blocked (e.g. console updates)..but struggle conceptually in ASP.Net. Thanks..

Comment: Not quite. Similar to your console app analogy, other requests (from other clients or the same client) are not blocked by waiting for a request thread to become free and start processing.

Comment: So how does it "know"/"track" which (UI/HTTP) thread to "come back to" (after db result)? [From Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx): `Async events in web applications are inherently strange beasts. Async void is meant for a fire and forget programming model. This works in Windows UI applications since the application sticks around until the OS kills it..there is guaranteed to be a UI thread that it can interact with. In web applications, this model falls apart since requests are by definition transient.`

Comment: @EdSF Brad Wilson's comment on that blog post is a good description for `async/await` in ASP.NET

Comment: Yup. Saw that and I'm sort of in "Uwe" mode in that thread :) It makes sense because the sample does multiple (io/network) tasks it needs to service the request. If I scope that to the above (assumed single) task of obtaining something from db, it would be #2 in Brad's comment. Performance is gained on the server (to process _other users' requests_), but not necessarily for the user making the original request (in above, the user invoking the login/db process). Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about the API in question but you can await async methods. While awaiting "other code" keeps executing.  After async method is done doing what-ever-it-was-doing, execution resumes from point which you awaited it. If you don't await, it acts like synchronous method.